# How to parse JSON from https website using Ada

Tags: rest, https, http-post, push, ada

I am trying to make a simple parser for an https website push, so trying to follow from the example from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/HTTP#Ada, just changing the address from a website.

So I  tried

```
    with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
    with AWS.Client;
    with AWS.Response;
    procedure Main_Other is
    begin
       Put_Line (AWS.Response.Message_Body
                 (AWS.Client.Get
                    (URL => "https://google.com")));
    end Main_Other;
```

But I got an exception

> raised PROGRAM_ERROR : aws-client.adb:398 finalize/adjust raised exception
>   [2020-04-02 10:41:20] process exited with status 1, elapsed time: 00.80s

So, any thoughts on how to fix that?

I'd like to parse the current status of some tables in a website, similar of making something like that in Python

```
    import pandas as pd
    def retrieve_json(json_url):
        return pd.read_json(json_url)
```

I'd like to code this solution the simplest way possible, even better not relying on AWS.

Please, and thanks.

Comment: Can you update your question with what code is around aws-client.adb:398?  Everytime I have seen this error message (in other files, not AWS particularly) it has been a GNAT bug, but it could be a problem with AWS.   Seeing the code in question might help determine.

Comment: The AWS build you're using might not have SSL support enabled (see answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you're using a build of AWS with SSL support disabled (SSL support is optional). Replacing `https` with `http` should do the trick. If an unsecured connection is not an option, either recompile AWS with SSL support enabled (see [here](https://docs.adacore.com/aws-docs/aws/building_aws.html#building) and [here](https://github.com/AdaCore/aws/blob/master/readme.txt)) or, if you're in a hurry and happen to develop on Linux,  fall back on `GNAT.Expect` and `wget` (tested with GNAT CE 2019):

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;   use Ada.Text_IO;
with GNAT.Expect;   use GNAT.Expect; 
with GNATCOLL.JSON; use GNATCOLL.JSON;

procedure Main is

   -------------------
   -- Download_JSON --
   -------------------

   function Download_JSON (URL : String) return JSON_Value is      

      Cmd    : constant String := "wget";
      Arg_1  : aliased String := "-q";   --  Turn off Wget's own messages.
      Arg_2  : aliased String := "-O";   --  Output response to ...
      Arg_3  : aliased String := "-";    --     ... standard output.
      Arg_4  : aliased String := URL;
      Status : aliased Integer;

      Response : String :=
        Get_Command_Output
          (Command    => Cmd,
           Arguments  => (1 => Arg_1'Unchecked_Access,
                          2 => Arg_2'Unchecked_Access,
                          3 => Arg_3'Unchecked_Access,
                          4 => Arg_4'Unchecked_Access),
           Input      => "",
           Status     => Status'Unchecked_Access);

   begin
      --  Omitting check of 'Status' for brevity.
      return Read (Response); 
   end;


   Root : JSON_Value;

begin

   Root := Download_JSON
     ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdaCore/gnatcoll-core/" &
        "master/testsuite/tests/json/validation/basic_object.json");

   Put_Line (Write (Root));

end Main;
```

**default.gpr**

```
with "gnatcoll.gpr";

project Default is
    for Source_Dirs use ("src");
    for Object_Dir use "obj";
    for Main use ("main.adb");
end Default;
```

**output**

```
$ ./main
{"a":1,"b":"a tringg","c":[1,2,3],"d":{"a":"a"},"e":null}
```

Comment: wget isn’t available in Apple’s macOS software, but curl works fine. You can get wget using brew or macports (I won’t, that’s just me)

Comment: I also tried the unsecure approach (even before), strange is that in the first execution it accepted the call. But as I run it again the server started refusing, so now it only answers 
Unable to retrieve data => Status Code :301 Reason :Moved Permanently

Comment: Or (from the suggested code)... as I had to install cygwin to get wget command, it is possible that GPS is not recognizing the new path. I will check.

Comment: Perfect now. I just fixed that path, restarted GPS and it run ok, even with my JSON link which is huge. Thank you very much.